# Red (error?) logcat messages about AsyncTasks when getLoaderManager().restartLoader() is called

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager

My app has a custom keyboard with custom user dictionary input suggestions that appear in a `ListView`. I just finished rewriting it so that it uses a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, a `ContentProvider`, and a `LoaderManager`. Sometimes I swap out the `SimpleCursorAdapter` in the `ListView` with a custom `ArrayAdapter` in order to provide other suggestions. I use `AsyncTask`s to get the data for the `ArrayAdapter`'s arrays.

When `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(WORDS_LOADER_ID, bundle, this);` gets called, LogCat in Eclipse shows some messages in red text. The `restartLoader` statement gets called at basically every key press because I need to requery the dictionary database. Here are the messages:

```
09-10 11:44:50.058: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=11: created from interp,name=AsyncTask #1
09-10 11:44:50.068: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=11: calling run(),name=AsyncTask #1
09-10 11:44:53.542: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=12: created from interp,name=AsyncTask #2
09-10 11:44:53.542: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=12: calling run(),name=AsyncTask #2
09-10 11:45:01.630: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=13: created from interp,name=AsyncTask #3
09-10 11:45:01.640: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=13: calling run(),name=AsyncTask #3
09-10 11:45:02.832: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=14: created from interp,name=AsyncTask #4
09-10 11:45:02.842: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=14: calling run(),name=AsyncTask #4
09-10 11:45:06.365: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=15: created from interp,name=AsyncTask #5
09-10 11:45:06.375: E/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=15: calling run(),name=AsyncTask #5
```

After reaching `name=AsyncTask #5` no more red messages are show, even when I continue to press other keys.

**KEY QUESTION:** Everything seems to be working ok in the app itself and no exceptions were thrown, but red means errors, right? Is there something I should be worried about?

I read the [LoaderManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) and also [How to Use Loaders in Android](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/) and as far as I can tell I have things set up correctly. Surely someone else has run into this, but I couldn't find anything on SO.

The fragment implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` and here are the overridden methods:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle) {

    String[] projection;
    String selection;
    String[] selectionArgs = { "" };
    String orderBy;

    switch (loaderID) {
    case WORDS_LOADER_ID:

        projection = new String[] { MyUserDictionary.Words._ID,
                MyUserDictionary.Words.WORD,
                MyUserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY,
                MyUserDictionary.Words.FOLLOWING };
        selection = MyUserDictionary.Words.WORD + " LIKE ?";
        selectionArgs[0] = bundle.getString("query") + "%";
        orderBy = MyUserDictionary.Words.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                MyUserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);

    default:
        Log.e("MyApp", "An invalid id was passed in");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor newCursor) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```